# Toggle() method with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help with jquery it's my first project and I'm having trouble with the event listener so I can click on my button and change the color of my title more than once. I need to alter the Second Title button can change the color of my title, I must set it up so that it can change the color back.

This requires the use of conditional statements in JavaScript.

I do not have to revert it back to the original color. I can pick a different color if I would like.

I've already tried the toggle method to hide and show the title when clicking on the button but I can't seem to get the color to change more than once. When I click on my button it does change it to yellow but only once.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#title2-button").click(function(){
    $("h2").toggleClass("#title2").css("color", "yellow");
  });
});
```

my expected result is to be able to click on my title2-button and toggle between colors more than​ once.

Comment: `#title2` seems like a weird name for a **class** ?

Answer (score 4):

You're setting the color to yellow everytime using `css()`, instead you should define the color in a stylesheet, and just toggle the class

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#title2-button").click(function(){
    $("h2").toggleClass("title2");
  });
});
```

```css
.title2 {color: red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="title2-button">CLICK ME</button>
<br/>
<h2>TOGGLES</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<button id="title2-button">Click Here</button>
<h2>Some Text</h2>
```

CSS:

```
.title2 {
    color: yellow;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#title2-button").click(function(){
        $("h2").toggleClass("title2");
    });
});
```